# What does triple at (@@@) mean in LaTeX?

Tags: letters

I was trying to make my own customization `letter` class and searching for the definition of the `\toname` command, I found this.

[image: some LaTeX definitions]

A triple at several times, but I wasn't able to find information so I decided to ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do

```
\begin{letter}{
  M. Y. Friend \\
  42 Some Rd \\
  Someplace
}
```

LaTeX does

```
\@processto{\leavevmode\ignorespaces #1}}
```

which in the example case becomes

```
\@processto{\leavevmode\ignorespaces M. Y. Friend \\ 42 Some Rd \\ Someplace }
```

This will first execute

```
\@xproc \leavevmode\ignorespaces M. Y. Friend \\ 42 Some Rd \\ Someplace \\@@@
```

According to the definition of `\@xproc`, LaTeX will take as `#1` everything up to the first `\\` and `#2` everything up to `\\@@@` and so it will do

```
\def\toname{\leavevmode\ignorespaces M. Y. Friend }
\def\toadddress{ 42 Some Rd \\ Someplace \\}
```

Suppose instead you do

```
\begin{letter}{M. Y. Friend}
```

The same process will lead to the call

```
\@xproc \leavevmode\ignorespaces M. Y. Friend \\@@@
```

In this case `#1` is again everything up to the first (and unique) `\\`, and `#2` is everything from `\\` (excluded) up to `@@@`, so it's empty.

The interesting case is therefore when `\toaddress` is not empty: a call to `\@yproc` is necessary in order to remove the trailing `\\` and indeed the call is

```
\@yproc #1@@@
```

which will become

```
\@yproc  \leavevmode\ignorespaces M. Y. Friend \\ 42 Some Rd \\ Someplace @@@
```

so it will end up in

```
\def\toaddress{ 42 Some Rd \\ Someplace }
```

Note that leading and trailing spaces are not omitted. They will “disappear” when `\opening` is executed, because `\toname` and `\toaddress` are typeset in the scope of `\raggedright`, precisely (line 192)

```
{\raggedright \toname \expandafter\\\toaddress \par}%
```

so in the example case we'll get

```
{\raggedright \leavevmode\ignorespaces M. Y. Friend \\ 42 Some Rd \\ Someplace \par}
```

Since `\\` also does `\par`, in this context, trailing spaces are suppressed by the implicit `\unskip`.

Why the strange `\expandafter`? Because a user might like some separation between the addressee's name and the address, so typing in something like

```
\begin{letter}{
  M. Y. Friend \\[1ex]
  42 Some Rd \\
  Someplace
}
```

Apply the same reasoning as above to see that in this case LaTeX does

```
\def\toaddress{[1ex] 42 Some Rd \\ Someplace }
```

and without the `\expandafter` the following `\\` would not *see* `[1ex]`.

The documentation indeed says

> A better fix would be to do a proper parsing but…

Answer (score 9):

Look at the next line where `\@xproc` is defined.

```
\long\def\@xproc #1\\#2@@@{\def\toname{#1}\def\toaddress{#2}}
\long\def\@yproc #1\\#2@@@{\def\toaddress{#2}}
```

There are #1 separated by `\\` and `#2` separated by `@@@`. So `@@@` is simply separetor of the second parameter. The usage of `\@xproc text\\@@@` (used in `\@processto`) does following: if `text` includes `\\` then `#2` is nonempty because `#2` includes the rest of `text` followed by `\\`. If `text` does not include `\\` then `#2` is empty because `#1` is whole `text` and we see nothing between `\\` and `@@@`. This behavior can be broken if someone write a `text` including `\\@@@` but macro programmer supposed that this has less probability.